# Android SMSManager sendTextMessage - I get sentIntent but never get deliveryIntent

Tags: android, sms

We're using the SMSManager on Android to send a text message to someone else from the device.

We've had reports of a user not receiving an SMS that we thought was delivered based on the fact that the sentIntent got called with Activity.RESULT_OK - but that seems to happen when the local SMS service simply queues the message for delivery and not necessarily when it is truly sent.

So I thought we should make use of the deliveryIntent.

The problem here is that I always get the sentIntent callback, but never the deliveryIntent one.

Any ideas?
Code is below, thanks.

```
        // The intent action to be unique so that we can have multiple
        // concurrent  pending intents.
        // http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html
        String intentAction = TAG + "-" + callbackId;  // callbackId is unique
        Intent intent = new Intent(intentAction);
        intent.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
        intent.putExtra("callbackId", callbackId);
        intent.putExtra("message", message);

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            cordova.getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);

        cordova.getActivity().registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
                String sentToPhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra("phoneNumber");
                String callbackId = intent.getStringExtra("callbackId");
                String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                int resultCode = getResultCode();
                int status = -1;
                String details = "";
                logger.log(Level.INFO, TAG + " SENT intent!! to: " +
                           sentToPhoneNumber + ", resultCode: " + resultCode);
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        status = 0;
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        details = "No service";
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        details = "Null PDU";
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        details = "Radio off";
                        status = 1;
                        break;
                }

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    obj.put("status", status);
                    obj.put("details", details);
                    obj.put("phone_number", sentToPhoneNumber);
                    obj.put("message", message);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                sendAsyncResultStatus(callbackId, obj);
                ctx.unregisterReceiver(this);
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(intentAction));

        // The intent action to be unique so that we can have multiple
        // concurrent  pending intents.
        // http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html
        String deliveryIntentAction = TAG + "-Delivery-" + callbackId;
        Intent deliveryIntent = new Intent(deliveryIntentAction);
        deliveryIntent.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
        deliveryIntent.putExtra("callbackId", callbackId);
        deliveryIntent.putExtra("message", message);

        PendingIntent deliveryPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            cordova.getActivity(), 0, deliveryIntent, 0);

        cordova.getActivity().registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, TAG + " DELIVERY intent YOYO!!");
                String sentToPhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra("phoneNumber");
                String callbackId = intent.getStringExtra("callbackId");
                String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                String pdu = intent.getStringExtra("pdu");
                logger.log(Level.INFO, TAG + " DELIVERY intent!! to: " +
                        sentToPhoneNumber + ", pdu: " + pdu);

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    obj.put("pdu", pdu);
                    obj.put("phone_number", sentToPhoneNumber);
                    obj.put("message", message);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                sendAsyncResultStatus(callbackId, obj);
                ctx.unregisterReceiver(this);
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(deliveryIntentAction));

        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveryPI);
```

Answer (score 6):

DeliveryIntent is dependent on DeliveryReports provided by some carriers.

Some Carriers do provide DeliveryReports and some don't. There are three categories in terms of carriers support of DliveryReports...

- Provider does not provide DeliveryReport at all.
- Provider always give a fake DeliveryReport (you will get an OK report even for invalid numbers)
- Provider does provide the delivery report.

The Complication doesn't stop here... If your provider (sending provider) does support delivery reports, you will get the delivery reports mostly when you are sending messages to subscribers of the same carrier. But when you send the message outside this carrier you may or may not get the delivery report. In most cases you won't.

This can be caused by a verity of reasons e.g.

- Destination provider doesn't support delivery reports
- Some of the intermediate SMS gateway(s) do not support delivery reports
- DeliveryReports of Destination carrier or some intermediate gateways are not compatible with those of Originating Carriers.

Delivery Reports in such case are not a guaranteed information in my knowledge so far.

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine that delivery intents depend on the reception of Return Receipts. The network provider needs to send these in order to make your program work.

You can do this by opening the "settings menu", browse to "SMS settings" and tick the box "Return receipt".

Comment: No, sorry, that isn't it. The delivery intent worked for me with and without having ticked the "Return Receipt" box.